# Google App Engine: ImportError: No module named appengine.ext

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to write a test for my GAE programme which uses the datastore.
Following [Google's Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting), I see that I should be adding the path to my SDK into my PYTHONPATH. 
I did this using:

```
import sys
sys.path.remove('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')    # Has a 'google' module, which I want to be sure isn't interfering.
sys.path.insert(1,'/home/olly/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine')
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/olly/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')
```

Then when the file is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "myapp_tests.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

I have installed the SDK in the location above, and looking in `/home/olly/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/` I found the `google` folder, which has an `__init__.py` in it, along with `appengine`. Basically, the folder structure looks good to me, with them all being named correctly and having `__init__.py` files.

In an interactive console, after running the commands above, I found that I could run:

```
import google
```

no problem, but when I tried

```
import google.appengine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named appengine
```

It was my understanding that having the `__init__.py()` files in the directories meant that they could be imported as above.
I also did a `sudo find / --name "google"`, and the only thing that showed up that is also in my PYTHONPATH was the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which I explicitly removed, and also inserted the rest of my paths in front of anyway.

I tried using GAE's own method of:

```
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

which added a whole lot of paths to sys.path, but still didn't help me make it work.

I also found that when I add `'/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/google'` to my paths, I can run:

```
import appengine.ext
```

but running:

```
from appengine.ext import ndb
```

causes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "booking_function_tests.py", line 16, in <module>
     from appengine.ext import ndb
  File "/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
     from tasklets import *
  File "/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 69, in <module>
     from .google_imports import apiproxy_stub_map
  File "/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/google_imports.py"    , line 11, in <module>
     from google3.storage.onestore.v3 import entity_pb
ImportError: No module named google3.storage.onestore.v3
```

Am I missing something really obvious? How should I go about importing ndb?

EDIT:
I'm running the latest SDK (1.9.34), but I have the following code in my google_imports.py:

```
try:
  from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb
  normal_environment = True
except ImportError:
  try:
    from google3.storage.onestore.v3 import entity_pb
    normal_environment = False
  except ImportError:
    # If we are running locally but outside the context of App Engine.
    try:
      set_appengine_imports()
      from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb
      normal_environment = True
    except ImportError:
      raise ImportError('Unable to find the App Engine SDK. '
                        'Did you remember to set the "GAE" environment '
                        'variable to be the path to the App Engine SDK?')
```

Also, `google.__path__` gives me the `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'` path which I thought I removed earlier. Here is an excerpt of how I'm removing it:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine')
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')
sys.path.remove('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')

import google
print google.__path__
print sys.path


['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google']
['/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/myapp', '/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib', '/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine/google', '/home/olly/Servers/google_appengine', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

So my sys.path is updated, but `import google` seems to still be importing from the no-longer-there path, which would be the crux of my problem I guess. Do I need to reload the path or something?

Comment: After the successful `import google`, what's the output of `print google.__file__`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'. 
__path__ on the other hand is giving me the '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', which I though I removed. This is probably the source of my problems. Although when I print sys.path, it doesn't show up in there...

Comment: For me, `print google.__ file __` in the dev server's remote shell displays the path in my local filesystem.  I'd strongly recommend following @billprin's advice and running your app in a virtualenv to avoid conflicts with anything on your machine. FWIW my test runner inserts the path to the sdk at the front of sys.path and then calls dev_appserver.fix_sys_path() and that works well.

Comment: In the end I just `pip uninstall protobuf`, which stopped the conflict for now. I don't particularly want to use a virtualenv at the moment, but will think about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I run into these problems a lot less by always running inside a  [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

I agree with snakecharmerrb you should get print `google.__file__` or `google.__path_` to figure out exactly what you're importing.

This snippet might also solve your problem:

```
import google

gae_dir = google.__path__.append('/path/to/appengine_sdk//google_appengine/google')
sys.path.insert(0, gae_dir) # might not be necessary

import google.appengine # now it's on your import path`
```

Answer (score 2):

Which version of app engine SDK are you using? I am using the latest SDK (1.9.34). I find the below snippet in my *~/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/google_imports.py* file

```
try:
    from google3.storage.onestore.v3 import entity_pb
    normal_environment = False
except ImportError:
    # If we are running locally but outside the context of App Engine.
    try:
      set_appengine_imports()
      from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb
      normal_environment = True
    except ImportError:
      raise ImportError('Unable to find the App Engine SDK. '
                    'Did you remember to set the "GAE" environment '
                    'variable to be the path to the App Engine SDK?')
```

But in your stack trace, after google3.storage import it doesn't seem to go inside the except clause.

So try the same code with latest SDK.